# Kafka Consumer Error Handling : confusion ErrorHandling / RetryTemplate

Tags: kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I try to have this following error handling when I consume my message :

- If there is a serialization error : Send message in DLT
- If there is an exception thrown by service in listener, retry X times depending the exception and send message in DLT in fail to retry or on choosen exception.

What I have (Spring kafka 2.5.5.RELEASE with 2.5.1 Kafka Client) is following :

```
@Bean(name = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, MyObject> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() throws ExceptionTechnique {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, MyObject> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(RECORD);
        factory.setRetryTemplate(retryTemplate());
        factory.setRecoveryCallback(context -> {
           Object record = context.getAttribute(RetryingMessageListenerAdapter.CONTEXT_RECORD);
           LOGGER_TECHNIQUE.error("Fail to handle message after {} retries. {}",
                context.getRetryCount(), record);
           return record;
        });
        factory.setErrorHandler(new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler(new DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer(kafkaOperations,
                        (cr, e) -> new TopicPartition("myTopicToRead.dlq", cr.partition())),
                        new FixedBackOff(10000L, 2L)));
        factory.setConcurrency(kafkaListenerConcurrency);
        factory.setStatefulRetry(true);

        return factory;
    }

@Bean
public RetryTemplate retryTemplate() {
    RetryTemplate retryTemplate = new RetryTemplate();
    retryTemplate.setBackOffPolicy(backOffPolicy());
    retryTemplate.setRetryPolicy(retryPolicy());
    return retryTemplate;
}

private BackOffPolicy backOffPolicy() {
    FixedBackOffPolicy fixedBackOffPolicy = new FixedBackOffPolicy();
    fixedBackOffPolicy.setBackOffPeriod(10000);
    return fixedBackOffPolicy;
}

private SimpleRetryPolicy retryPolicy() {
    Map<Class<? extends Throwable>, Boolean> exceptionMap = new HashMap<>();

    exceptionMap.put(IllegalArgumentException.class, false);
    exceptionMap.put(TimeoutException.class, false);
    exceptionMap.put(ListenerExecutionFailedException.class, true);
    // Custom exception
    exceptionMap.put(MyTechnicalException.class, false);
    exceptionMap.put(MyFunctionalException.class, false);

    return new SimpleRetryPolicy(3, exceptionMap, true);
}
```

Now, if I send not serializable message, my message goes to DLT without retry -> OK !

In my `@KafkaHandler`, I have a `throw new MyTechnicalException`, catched and rethrown.

I should have no retry, but I got 2 retrys, with 20sec each (instead of 10 ?), and a message sent to DLT after 2 retries.

If I remove the errorHandler, no surprise, 3 attempts and my log error message is displayed... but I need to send to DLQ...

If I remove the RetryTemplate and RecoveryCallback, no surprise, but all exception are retried...

Questions :

1. Is there a way to handle my use case ? How ?
2. What's the difference between RecoveryCallback and ErrorHandler in the factory configuration ?
3. How does the retry depending Exception type work ? Does it works with our Exception ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retries at the listener level have been deprecated since the error handlers have evolved to cover all the functionality that the `RetryTemplate` provides - back off, exception classification, etc.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/1886

Comment: Do you have example with retry according the exception for exemple ? Because we don't want to unstack a topic to fill another if the database is gone for eg.

Comment: See [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#seek-to-current) about retryable Vs. not retryable exceptions, and using a function to select the `BackOff` to use for particular exceptions. If you still need help, I can put together an example when I am back at work in the next couple of days.

Comment: I will try to do a POC of that :) At first impression, the "Retry only this exception" is a bit hard to do, but if you do the opposite (do not retry all exception except this one), it seems OK to do it :) Thank you for your fast answer

Comment: See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/blob/afb205347cb77428c64ed54637ac67a8825c6a7f/spring-kafka/src/main/java/org/springframework/kafka/listener/FailedRecordProcessor.java#L74-L95 where you can make the default not retry and specify retryables. Using a function is useful too: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/blob/afb205347cb77428c64ed54637ac67a8825c6a7f/spring-kafka/src/main/java/org/springframework/kafka/listener/FailedRecordProcessor.java#L113-L122

Comment: I will check that, thank you very much !